# How can I delete the search history in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

Gmail keeps suggesting searches I used years ago and I want to remove them, but there isn't an option or it isn't in an obvious place. Can I delete the Gmail internal search history?

Answer (score 8):

**Note:** As of around the start of 2017 this option seems to have disappeared, and as of 2017-09-20 I can't find another way to do it.

To delete specific entries from the Gmail search box auto-complete list:

1. Go to the search box in Gmail
2. Type the first part of the search you want to delete
3. When the dropdown appears with one of the options you don't want, hover over that option with your mouse
4. An "x" will appear on the right side of that entry - click it to remove that search from your Gmail search history

Comment: +1; close, but then you need to know what to delete.

Comment: Didn't work as the results showed up again when I logged back in. I kinda figured it out that it you need to clear your browser cache/history as well and it takes about 12 hours for the results to go away completely.

Giving a bounty nevertheless since it solves.

Comment: @apnerve - That's interesting the browser cache played into it as well, but glad to hear it worked in the end.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra - That's true, and not to mention it's time consuming. It'd be nice if there was an interface to actually list all the items and delete any you want, but until that comes around, I think we're stuck with this.

Comment: Doesn't exactly show the internal search history, only on a case-by-case basis, which is not really what's needed.

Comment: @warsong: Then you should send a feature request to Google. To do that Go to gmail.com > Settings > Send Feedback.

Comment: Done. Let's see if they listen.

Comment: I dont see that "x" anywhere when hovering an entry. Is it still working for other people?

Comment: @MasterScrat Looks like it's not an option anymore. :( I'll update the answer with a note, because as of now I can't find another way to do this.

Comment: I had to dig a bit to clear my junk history in personal gmail so hope this helps the next person. History can be cleared via the google my activity page. (https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity?utm_source=udc&utm_medium=r&restrict=waa&product=4)

Answer (score -2):

On Android phone to clear Gmail email searches...

Click on Gmail app to open.

Click on menu.

Click on settings.

Click on general settings.

Click on menu again.

Click on clear searches.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't mention the Android app anywhere.

Answer (score -2):

I figured it out myself and it worked for me. Go to *Settings* in your Android then go to *Application Manager*. Go to ALL and then click on Gmail. Click **Clear data**.

Now open Gmail, your previous accounts are already there but the search history is gone!

Comment: This doesn't affect the search on the Gmail web-app in any way. Do you know which part of Stack Overflow you're in right now?

Answer (score -4):

You can see and delete your search history at https://history.google.com/history/

Comment: That is for another product, not for Gmail.